# How to group interconnected elements in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, cluster-analysis

I have a data frame that looks like this.
Elements from the col1 are connected indirectly with elements in col2.
for example 1 is connected with 2 and 3.
and 2  is connected with 3. Therefore 1 should be connected with 3 as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(col1=c(1,1,2,5,5,6), 
              col2=c(2,3,3,6,7,7))
df1
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>    col1  col2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     2     3
#> 4     5     6
#> 5     5     7
#> 6     6     7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want my data to look like this

```r
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2  group1
#> 2     1     3  group1
#> 3     2     3  group1
#> 4     5     6  group2
#> 5     5     7  group2
#> 6     6     7  group2
```

I would appreciate any possible help to solve this riddle.
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
g <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed = TRUE)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(col3 = str_c("group", clusters(g)$membership[as.character(col1)]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   col1  col2 col3  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     2 group1
2     1     3 group1
3     2     3 group1
4     5     6 group2
5     5     7 group2
6     6     7 group2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `igraph` option

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(
        col3 =
            paste0("group", {
                graph_from_data_frame(.) %>%
                    components() %>%
                    membership()
            }[as.character(col1)])
    )
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   col1  col2 col3  
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     2 group1
2     1     3 group1
3     2     3 group1
4     5     6 group2
5     5     7 group2
6     6     7 group2
```